# How to add a new variant to MUI's default typography (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

This question rose when I was trying out the MUI official instruction [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#adding-amp-disabling-variants).

1. in file `newTheme.ts`, customize the primary color, and add a  new variant type `post`:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

const newTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#f00" // red
    }
  },

  // uncommenting caused compiler error:
  // Type '{ poster: { color: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'TypographyOptions | ((palette: Palette) => TypographyOptions) | undefined'.
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'poster' does not exist in type 'TypographyOptions | ((palette: Palette) => TypographyOptions)'.ts(2322)
  // typography: {
  //   poster: {
  //     color: '#f00',
  //   },
  // },
});

export default newTheme;
```

2. under the same directory, added a file `newTheme.d.ts`:

```
import { ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypographyVariants {
    poster: React.CSSProperties;
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface TypographyVariantsOptions {
    poster?: React.CSSProperties;
  }
}

// Update the Typography's variant prop options
declare module '@mui/material/Typography' {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    poster: true;
  }
}
```

I have two problems:

1. received the compiler error if I tried to add in the `poster` variant
2. the primary color didn't turn red

here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-typography-variant-svfhzj?file=/src/App.tsx)

What had I missed?

Comment: You can create a theme provider. Wrap your entire App.js in the provider. Then in the theme provider code, you can create as many variants as you want for every MUI component : https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/

Comment: Thank you - I had all that in place already. It wasn't shown here for clarity. Your example talked about customizing the 'palette' (and I have tried them out, hence completing the whole ThemeProvider->use new theme route). My task here was specifically about customizing 'typography', and it is this compiler error that I wish to address here.

Comment: I see, could you throw it into a codesandbox ? Will be easier for everyone to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: I will spend some time to figure out how to use codesandbox first, will do thanks - did you remove your answer provided earlier? I was going to try it out but could not found it anyway. Assuming that was one possible way to go, can you please also show the step to use it, or it's simply `<Typography variance='newFoo'/>`?

Answer (score 4):

The code in your question has the following line:

```
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
```

This is importing the v4 version of `createTheme`. You shouldn't be mixing any `@material-ui/*` packages (v4) with `@mui/*` packages (v5). You should be using v5 for everything.

Here's a working example using a custom Typography variant:

**demo.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    subtitle1: {
      fontSize: 12
    },
    body1: {
      fontWeight: 500
    },
    button: {
      fontStyle: "italic"
    },
    poster: {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
});

export default function TypographyVariants() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1">subtitle</Typography>
        <Typography variant="poster">poster</Typography>
        <Typography>body1</Typography>
        <Button>Button</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**typography.d.ts**

```
import "@mui/material/styles";
import "@mui/material/Typography";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface TypographyVariants {
    poster: React.CSSProperties;
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface TypographyVariantsOptions {
    poster?: React.CSSProperties;
  }
}

// Update the Typography's variant prop options
declare module "@mui/material/Typography" {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    poster: true;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Typography variant]

Comment: thank you @Ryan, particularly for pointing out the discrepancy between MUI 4 and 5. This had been the source for lots of my pain. The company I worked for was still on MUI 4, and a lot of the online examples I tried to learn from used MUI 5. Sometimes I mixed them up without realizing. In this case, my hands were tied and was forced to used MUI 4 - but maybe many people are on the same boat and would require an answer for MUI 4. I have created the Code Sand Box (thanks for introducing this tool to me), and updated my question - now the color override didn't work either..

Comment: @Steve The code in your sandbox is still using the `@mui/material` (v5) packages rather than importing from `@material-ui/core`.

Comment: No, Its good that he shows the more modern version. This is exactly what you need. Please accept the answer as it solves the problem for all modern MUI projects.